# Not applicable for the arguments sorting error

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I try to sort but I got the compilation error

> The method `sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)` in the type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments `(List<Map.Entry<T,Integer>>, HashMapHistogramComparator<T>)`

This is my code:

```
public class HashMapHistogramIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List<HashMap.Entry<T,Integer>> items;
    Iterator<HashMap.Entry<T,Integer>> lst;

    public HashMapHistogramIterator(HashMapHistogram<T> hshMp) {
        this.items = new ArrayList<HashMap.Entry<T,Integer>>();
        this.items.addAll(hshMp.getAllMap());
        Collections.sort(this.items, new HashMapHistogramComparator<T>(hshMp));
        this.lst = this.items.iterator();
    }
}
```

And that's my comperator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class HashMapHistogramComparator<T> implements Comparator<T>{
    HashMapHistogram<T> hshMp;

    public HashMapHistogramComparator(HashMapHistogram<T> hshMp){
        this.hshMp = hshMp;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T arg0, T arg1) {
        int val1 = this.hshMp.getValue(arg0);
        int val2 = this.hshMp.getValue(arg1);
        return Integer.compare(val2,val1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to sort `HashMap.Entry`, then your comparator should be `class HashMapHistogramComparator<T> implements Comparator<HashMap.Entry<T,Integer>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you **compare** T , your `this.items` are probably of wrong type:

```
   this.items = new ArrayList<T>();
   this.items.addAll(hshMp.keySet());
```

If you itend to compare a `List` of `Map.Entry` by their values, you should *tell the Comparator*:

```
 HashMapHistogramComparator<T> implements Comparator<HashMap.Entry<T,Integer>> {
  HashMapHistogram<T> hshMp;

  public HashMapHistogramComparator(HashMapHistogram<T> hshMp){
    this.hshMp = hshMp;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(HashMap.Entry<T,Integer> arg0, HashMap.Entry<T,Integer> arg1) {
    int val1 = arg0.getValue();
    int val2 = arg1.getValue();
    return Integer.compare(val2,val1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: i need it to have key and value and than sort by value

Comment: i just saw that i need only to return the key so i dont care about the value in the list so the first thing worked thanks!